# send POST from action.submit in Teams

Tags: json, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

here's a newb question. I created an adaptive-card for use in outlook that has an action.http that sends a POST to a webhook url with a single variable entered by the user, which is an email address. This is working great, now i want to use that to send the same message to the user in Teams and as a notification in Windows. I am using Flow and selected the "Post your own adaptive card as the Flow bot to a user". I then entered my json code that i used for the adaptive card for outlook but it doesnt work. So I would assume since the action.http seems to only be available for outlook that I have to change that action for teams to be an action.submit, but then im stuck, where is it submitting to? how do i have it do a POST to my webhook url with the variable data entered by the user?

I did make sure i have the flow bot added to teams and logged in and approved for use for my user for testing. I have also added App Studio to teams and then used it's "card editor" to tweak and practice with the code for the adaptive-card in Teams. I changed my action to be action.submit and finally got a button to appear in the card in Teams but i dont know how to deliver the data which should be the email the user enters, "{\"email\":\"{{email.value}}\"}" to a url using a POST. I dont know what happens when they hit the action.submit button. I have also scoured the internet and microsoft docs for a better understanding but there are no examples of this that I have been able to find.

I used this in the original Adaptive.Card for outlook

```
            {
                "type": "ActionSet",
                "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.Http",
                        "title": "Button Text",
                        "method": "POST",
                        "body": "{\"email\":\"{{email.value}}\"}",
                        "url": "mywebhookurl"
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `Action.Http` is currently not supported in non-Outlook Adaptive Cards. Therefore, you currently have no way of using a Teams Adaptive card to reach your webhook URL.

`Action.Submit` is generally meant to go to a bot. In this case, it would be Flow, but [this isn't currently supported](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/2924) in Flow.

Thankfully,

> The fully-custom / interactive card is a scenario we have on our radar.

So unfortunately, you're not doing anything wrong. It just isn't supported yet. I'd imagine that this is why the "Post your own adaptive card..." flow is still in preview:

[image]